# Expired cert when accessing SO

Tags: ssl, certificate

When I try to open https://stackoverflow.com/ Chrome says:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
*.stackexchange.com
Let's Encrypt Authority X3
05.10.2020-03.01.2021
```

I use windows 10.

Curl and other browsers say the same thing.

Computer time is properly set.

Once in a while SO works.

Other devices from the same network don't have that problem.

I have no idea what else i can do to fix it. Does anyone have any idea?